# How to get id of HTML elements

Tags: php, html, domdocument

In PHP, I want to parse a HTML page and obtain the ids of certain elements. I am able to obtain all the elements, but unable to obtain the ids.

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML('<html><body><h3 id="h3-elem-id">A</h3></body></html>');
$divs = $doc->getElementsByTagName('h3');
foreach($divs as $n) {
    (...)
}
```

Is there a way to also obtain the id of the element?

Thank you.

Comment: Have a look at http://php.net/manual/en/domelement.getattribute.php

You should be able to do $n->getAttribute("id") inside the loop.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want the `id` attribute values, then you need to use `getAttribute()`:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML('<html><body><h3 id="h3-elem-id">A</h3></body></html>');
$divs = $doc->getElementsByTagName('h3');
foreach($divs as $n) {
   echo $n->getAttribute('id') . '<br/>';
}
```

Comment: @MobileCushion im glad i was able to help

Comment: hello @ShoaibChikate, i think there is a time gap between accepting answers, 15 mins if im not mistaken